# Using JavaScript's history.pushState with Angular's $location.search()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, single-page-application

Before I get into the long-winded explanation and the code, let me just say that I understand that my implementation of this system is a bit of a hack-job. The goal was to implement a linking feature on a SPA application without completely overhauling what was already done with Angular and the Bootstrap modals. I'll wager that I probably could have accomplished something better with directives, but my understanding of directives is lacking.

The following is a function that is launched when the system detects a change in the URL. The new URL parameters are passed and are used to query the back-end for content.

```
    function handleUrlParamsModalLaunch(data) {
        /*Ensure modal is not displaying any data*/
        vm.modalData = {};
        vm.selectedTab = null;

        /*Show modal loading gif*/
        vm.isModalLoading = true;
        $("#contentPartModal").modal();

        /*Call the content service to return the clicked content article*/
        contentpartservice.getContentItem(data.id, data.type).then(function (contentItem) {
            if (contentItem) {
                vm.isModalLoading = false;
                vm.modalData = contentItem;
                return;
            } else {
                closeModal("#contentPartModal").then(function () {
                    vm.isModalLoading = false;
                    logger.error('An error occurred while fetching content');
                });
                return;
            }
        }, function (error) {
            closeModal("#contentPartModal").then(function () {
                vm.isModalLoading = false;
                logger.error('An error occurred while fetching content');
            });
            return;
        });
    }
```

The following function is run when a link is clicked. It adds the parameters needed to retrieve content from the back-end to the URL.

```
    function setUrl(contentId, contentType) {

        var urlParams = $location.search();
        if (urlParams.q) {
            $location.search({ q: urlParams.q, type: contentType, id: contentId });
        } else {
            $location.search({ type: contentType, id: contentId });
        }

        return;
    }
```

The following is where the solution starts to look like a hack job. I need to remove the parameters from the URL when the modal closes, but I couldn't find a way to catch the Bootstrap modal close event from the scope of my Angular controller (where the above functions are being called). Instead, I wrote the following JavaScript code in script tags that does it without Angular's $location dependency.

```
<script>
    /*
     * Detect the closing of a modal window and modify the URL to no longer display linking information.
     * Not handled in Angular because Angular lacks a suitable way to detect a bootstrap modal close.
     */
    $('#contentPartModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        var pageUrl = $.url();
        var pageParams = pageUrl.param();

        if (pageParams.q) {
            if (history.pushState) {
                var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?q=' + pageParams.q;
                window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);
            }
        } else {
            if (history.pushState) {
                var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
                window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the resulting bug. The first time you click on a link, all of these functions run fine. The modal is opened with the correct data being displayed. When you close the modal, the URL parameters are removed from view. When you go to click on another link, the setUrl function is called, but the URL doesn't actually change. This results in the modal pop-up not opening. A second click on any link, and everything works as expected. The resulting bug is that each link needs to be clicked twice after the first time the modal has been opened.

Any hints to the cause of this bug would be much appreciated. I'd also accept an idea for a better implementation that would help me circumvent the issue altogether.

Thanks,

Matt